# Is there a script to automatically re-deploy a subgraph?

Tags: the-graph, subgraph, graphs, graphql

I have a subgraph that is running on a EC2 Instance and I want to be able to re-compile it, re-generate it and re-deploy it every time a configuration changes. When I say configuration, I refer to the smart contracts I want to track events for.

The commands I have to run are the following:

```
npx graph-compiler --config configs/config.json --include node_modules/@openzeppelin/subgraphs/src/datasources --export-schema --export-subgraph

graph create generated/sample --node http://127.0.0.1:8020

graph deploy --ipfs http://localhost:5001 --node http://localhost:8020 generated/sample ./generated/sample.subgraph.yaml
```

Does anybody have done this before and can provide an example of some scripts I can run to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the scripts I finally created to achieve this:

**compile.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
  echo "$0: Missing arguments"
  exit 1
elif [ $# -gt 2 ];
then
  echo "$0: Too many arguments: $@"
  exit 1
else
  npx graph-compiler --config $1 --include node_modules/@openzeppelin/subgraphs/src/datasourc>
fi
```

**create.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

graph create generated/sample --node http://127.0.0.1:8020
```

**deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

graph deploy --ipfs http://localhost:5001 --node http://localhost:8020 generated/sample ./gen>
```